# How to append div element onclick in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to have a self-appending input box when I click on an "add more" button.

What I currently have is the following, in which I hope that when I click on the link, the input will append itself with each click.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" slide-show="showInput">
  <input name="item.id">
</div>
<div>
  <a href ng-click="showInput=true">add more</a>
<div>
```

Comment: Push to items on ng-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new item in items array.

```
function SampleCtrl ($scope) {
   $scope.items = [obj1,obj2,obj3];
   $scope.showItem = false;
   $scope.addItem = function () {
       //it's up to you how you want to structure the new_object.
       var new_object;
       $scope.showInput = true;
       $scope.items.push(new_object);
   }
}
```

In your `ng-click` call the `addItem` function instead.

Comment: you mean: `$scope.items.push(new_object);` ?